# Find if a value exists anywhere in a second column and return a result

Tags: sql, oracle, birt

I need to match one column data to another column data, if the first column exists anywhere in the second then the result should be '0.5' (1/2) else if  doesn't match or crossing  both columns result should be '0'(zero).

I have table which contain following data:

```
Job_Id   link_Id   
2         3
3         2
4         5
5         4
6         null
7         8
8         7
10        null
```

Expected result :

```
Job_Id  link_Id  cycle
2         3        0.5
3         2        0.5
4         5        0.5
5         4        0.5
6         null     0
7         8        0.5
8         7        0.5
10        null     0
```

[image]

My query :

```
select t.job_id
     , t.link_id
     , round((case when t.link_job_id IS NULL then 1 else null end))/2 cycles 
   from T_QCMS_JOB_STATE_HIS t
```

This doesn't quite work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just a standard outer join?

```
select a.job_id, b.link_id, case when b.link is not null then 0.5 else 0 end cycle
from tb a left outer join tb b
on a.job_id = b.link_id;
```

Written free hand as no create table and data is provided. Adopt as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Your table looks like it might be hierarchical, in which case a [recursive CTE/sub-query factoring clause](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BCEJGIBG) may help you in the future.

To obtain your current result though, you just need to do a self-join:

```
select coalesce(l.job_id, j.job_id) as job_id
     , l.link_id
     , case when l.link_id is not null then 0.5 else 0 end as cycle
  from t_qcms_job_state_his j
  left outer join t_qcms_job_state_his l
    on j.job_id = l.link_id;

    JOB_ID    LINK_ID      CYCLE
---------- ---------- ----------
         2          3         .5
         3          2         .5
         4          5         .5
         5          4         .5
         7          8         .5
         8          7         .5
        10                     0
         6                     0

8 rows selected.
```

The outer join is there to deal with the fact that not all link IDs exist.

Another non-ANSI compliant way, but which only involves a single table scan would be to use Oracle's [`FIRST`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm) function, this is significantly more confusing but will be more efficient:

```
with the_data as(
select job_id
     , max(link_id) keep (dense_rank first order by case when job_id = link_id then 0 else 1 end) as link_id
  from t_qcms_job_state_his
 group by job_id
       )
select job_id
     , link_id
     , case when link_id is not null then 0.5 else 0 end as cycle
  from the_data
```

Answer (score 2):

Use lead and lag functions for your required output

```
    SELECT job_id
    ,link_id
    ,nvl(CASE 
        WHEN lead(job_id) OVER (
                ORDER BY job_id
                ) = link_id
            AND lead(link_id) OVER (
                ORDER BY job_id
                ) = job_id
            OR lag(job_id) OVER (
                ORDER BY job_id
                ) = link_id
            AND lag(link_id) OVER (
                ORDER BY job_id
                ) = job_id
            THEN 0.5
        END,0) status1
FROM Table1
```